# how to set languages for gnome-text-editor spell checker?

Tags: gnome, 22.10, spell-checking, gnome-text-editor

I have a 22.10 Ubuntu system, system language is German. How to add German to gnome text editor? I have 5 flavors of English language, four of them I don't want to see, but I can't find any possibility to add some other languages for the spell checking.

[image: hmm, what mood should I choose today?]

Answer (score 3):

Ok, somehow gnome-text-editor uses enchant for spell checking. Enchant looks for another spell checkers on system like hunspell, aspell, etc. The system is scanned for dictionaries and if they are present use them.

So I had to install `hunspell-de-de` to get German language into gnome-text-editor. That was not so difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Author of Text Editor here.

Spell checking in GNOME Text Editor is provided by "Enchant 2". Enchant is itself an aggregator of spell-checking back-ends.

It supports a number of back-ends such as Hunspell, Aspell and others. So you'll want to install German support for one of those engines and Text Editor will pick it up on the next restart.

I don't use Ubuntu, so I can't give you the exact names of the packages you'll need to install.